# Autocomplete suggestions don't appear

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I have some problem.
When I generate autocomplete programmatically, for example:

```
$("#body_person_name").keyup(function () {
    if ($("#body_person_name").val().length < 3) return;
    var suggestions = [];
    $.getJSON("some_external_api_resource.com/get_some_names", function (data, status) {
        $.each(data, function (key, value) {
            suggestions.push({
                value: value,
                data: key
            });
        });
    });

    $("#body_person_name").autocomplete({
        lookup: suggestions,
        minChars: 3,
        autoFocus: true,
        onSelect: function (suggestion) {
            //...
        }
    });
});
```

Suggestion list doesn't appear straight after the letters were typed, the user need to click out of input and then click on input with autocomplete to see some suggestions.

I don't really understand how to solve this problem=(

Comment: Because `getJSON` is asynchronous and `suggestions` wil not be accessible directly. What plugin do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, turns out you were approaching this whole thing the wrong way ..

If you read the jQuery UI Autocomplete documentation, you'd see the options for everything you need. It's all pretty much built into it for you.

```
  $(function () {

      $("#body_person_name").autocomplete({
          source: function (request, response) {
              $.ajax({
                  url: 'your_url',
                  success: function (data) { // modify your response here.
                      response($.map(data, function (value, key) {
                          console.log(value, key);
                          return {
                              value: value,
                              data: key,
                              label: value
                          };
                      }));
                  }
              });
          },
          minLength: 3, // set the min characters to type to initiate ajax call
          select: function (event, ui) {
              console.log(ui.item);
          }
      })
  });
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. I've corrected this mistake, but problem still exists. Suggestions don't appear straight after the letters were typed. We need to focus out and then focus on input to see suggestion list.

Comment: Try using .`.on(input, fn)` instead of `keyup`